# How to handle UI changes from interaction with a view when using a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-recyclerview

If we have a `RecyclerView` that will have views of different type we can inflate the view we need based on an item type e.g.

```
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int type) {
        View view = null;
        switch (type) {
            case TYPEX:  
               view = LayoutInflater
                    .from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.typex, viewGroup, false);
                    return new ViewHolderX(view);
            case TYPEY:
                view = LayoutInflater
                    .from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.typey, viewGroup, false);
                return new ViewHolderY(view);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

So far so good. The views then are reusable in the `ViewHolder`

Question:
If `TYPEX` view has a button that on press changes something in the view e.g. the background color, this means that when the view is recycled the color will be different for other items that the user never pressed the button for.
How can this be addressed since it would not be related to any condition of the data that the view has to display from the adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store your Property [**background color**] inside model and make decision based on that.

```
class Model {

    ...

    private int backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;

    public int getBackgroundColor() {
        return backgroundColor;
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(int backgroundColor) {
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    ...

}
```

Handle click here and update background color.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SuggestionHomeAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final Model model = modelItems.get(position);

    holder.rootView.setBackgroundColor(model.getBackgroundColor());

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(model.getBackgroundColor() != 0xFFFF0000){
                model.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It persists with model by position not view. So only those item affected that are click by user. Thanks

Comment: How is that class associated with the `ViewHolders` or with the specific views in the list?

Comment: If each view has a `Model` that means that a recycled view would have a model with an updated color

Comment: Here `Model` is an example. Your different type of Recycler Item should associated with some model, right? I mean that model

Comment: No I don't use a model. I just set the data I get directly. If I use a model as you describe, then on button click the model for that view will change. Now on recycler the model doesn't change right? So the model would still show the color for the updated state even though the user didn't interact with that view. Could you please show me an example of using a model?

Comment: This helps but it assumes that the `Model` or that attribute is relevant for all positions though while I have a `RecyclerView` with completely different views. And although a background change can be relevant to any view what if the change was something more specific to a specific view type?

Comment: You have to handle `ViewType` in your own logic. I just give you the idea to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Inside `onBindViewHolder` you also have to check `ViewType` and take decision accordingly.