# Why Every Other Toggle Button is Activated as i Scroll?

Tags: android

[image]

> I am displaying a toggle button inside RecyclerView
>
> hadees_contents.xml

```
<ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle_btn"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/unfavorite"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />
```

> HadeesAdapter.java:

```
public class HadeesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HadeesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<ToggleModel> toggleModelList;
private String[] data;
Context context;

public HadeesAdapter(List<ToggleModel> toggleModelList, String[] data, Context context) {
    this.toggleModelList = toggleModelList;
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hadees_contents, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final ToggleModel toggleModel = toggleModelList.get(position);
    if(toggleModel.isFavorite())
        holder.toggle_btn.setBackgroundResource(toggleModel.getToggled());
    else
        holder.toggle_btn.setBackgroundResource(toggleModel.getUntoglled());


    String title = data[position];
    holder.textView.setText(title);
    ((ViewHolder) holder).copybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "dfdfd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            cm.setText(holder.textView.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Copied :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    holder.whatsapText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "dfdbnbnbnfd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
                whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, holder.textView.getText().toString());
                Log.e("WCLICKED", holder.textView.getText().toString());

            try {
                context.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "WhatApp not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    holder.share_txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Lal Bunglow Maszid");
                String shareMessage= holder.textView.getText().toString().trim();
                //shareMessage = shareMessage + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +"\n\n";
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
                context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "choose one"));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                //e.toString();
                Log.e("Error in sharing","error");
            }

        }
    });




    holder.toggle_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (toggleModel.isFavorite)
                toggleModel.setFavorite(false);
            else
                toggleModel.setFavorite(true);

            notifyItemChanged(position);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.length;
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView ;

    ImageView copybutton,share_txt;


    ImageView whatsapText;
    ToggleButton toggle_btn;


    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        copybutton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.copybutton);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        whatsapText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.whatsApp_txt);
        share_txt= itemView.findViewById(R.id.share_txt);
        toggle_btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.toggle_btn);

        String abc = textView.getText().toString();

    }
}
```

}

> Hadees.java:

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hadees, container, false);

    ImageView copybutton= root.findViewById(R.id.copybutton);
    final TextView textView=root.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ImageView whatsapText=root.findViewById(R.id.whatsApp_txt);

    myrecyclerview=(RecyclerView)root.findViewById(R.id.myrecyclerview);
    myrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

> As I scroll Down inside the RecyclerView, i found many of these toggle buttons are automatically activated.
>
> Here is My Haddes Adapter's onBindViewHolder :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

   holder.toggle_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (holder.toggle_btn.isChecked()){
               // flag=1;
                holder.toggle_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorited);
               // intent.putExtra("MRF", mrf.getText().toString().trim());
               // Log.e("DATA :",mrf.getText().toString().trim());
               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Added to Favorites Successfully !"+ flag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                holder.toggle_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unfavorite);
             //   flag=0;
               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Removed from favorites"+flag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

       }
    });

}
```

> Can anyone suggest why this is Happening and how to fix it ?
>   Model Class :

```
package com.zedapps.elon;

public class ToggleModel {

    int toggled = R.drawable.favorited;
    int untoglled = R.drawable.unfavorite;

    public ToggleModel(int toggled, int untoglled) {
        this.toggled = toggled;
        this.untoglled = untoglled;
    }

    public int getToggled() {
        return toggled;
    }

    public int getUntoglled() {
        return untoglled;
    }
}
```

> Here is my Hadees.java file :

```
    /**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Hadees extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView myrecyclerview;
    ToggleButton toggle_btn;

    List<ToggleModel> toggleModelList;

    public Hadees() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hadees, container, false);

        ImageView copybutton= root.findViewById(R.id.copybutton);
        final TextView textView=root.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView whatsapText=root.findViewById(R.id.whatsApp_txt);

        toggleModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        myrecyclerview=(RecyclerView)root.findViewById(R.id.myrecyclerview);
        myrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


        String[] details={
                "Sharab se bacho isiliye kyunki wo har burayi ki chabi hai.❞\n        Allah ke Rasool (ﷺ)" +
                        "(Hadith: Mustadrak: 7313)",
                "‟Tum ek doosre ko taana na diya karo aur naa ek doosre ko bure naamo se pukaaro.’\n" +
                        " Surah Al-Hujurat 49:11",
                "❝ Ramzan ka wo Mahina jis me Quraan ka Nuzool hua saari Insaniyat ki Hidayat aur Rahnumai ke liye.❞\n" +
                        " Surah Baqrah 2:185",

        };

        myrecyclerview.setAdapter(new HadeesAdapter(toggleModelList,details,getActivity()));




        return root;
    }

}
```

Comment: Add your `HadeesAdapter`'s `onBindViewHolder` code

Comment: Hope this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58578266/2637449

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman added , please check

Comment: Check above link, hope this will help you. If not then let me know

Comment: You have to store **checked/unchecked** state in a property of model to persist with scrolling and also set the default one first

Comment: ok, i am trying and will let you know :)

Comment: I also added Model Class, please have a look @Md.Asaduzzaman

Comment: Now i got this Error :    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: You are passing empty `toggleModelList` which causes the exception. Why you pass two list in the Adapter. It is useless. Check my updated answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also add favorite state in your model

```
public class ToggleModel {

    int toggled = R.drawable.favorited;
    int untoglled = R.drawable.unfavorite;
    boolen isFavorite = false;
    String title;

    public ToggleModel(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getToggled() {
        return toggled;
    }

    public int getUntoglled() {
        return untoglled;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setFavorite(boolean favorite) {
        isFavorite = favorite;
    }

    public boolean isFavorite() {
        return isFavorite;
    }
}
```

Then handle this in your `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final ToggleModel toggleModel = toggleModelList.get(position);
    if(toggleModel.isFavorite())
       holder.toggle_btn.setBackgroundResource(toggleModel.getToggled());
    else
       holder.toggle_btn.setBackgroundResource(toggleModel.getUntoglled());

    //Set title from model
    holder.textView.setText(toggleModel.getTitle());

    holder.toggle_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (toggleModel.isFavorite)
               toggleModel.setFavorite(false);
            else
               toggleModel.setFavorite(true);

            notifyItemChanged(position);
       }
    });
}
```

And inside your `Hadees` fragment set the list like below:

```
toggleModelList = new ArrayList<>();
toggleModelList.add(new ToggleModel("Sharab se bacho isiliye kyunki wo har burayi ki chabi hai.❞\n        Allah ke Rasool (ﷺ)" +
                        "(Hadith: Mustadrak: 7313)"));
toggleModelList.add(new ToggleModel("‟Tum ek doosre ko taana na diya karo aur naa ek doosre ko bure naamo se pukaaro.’\n" +
                        " Surah Al-Hujurat 49:11"));
toggleModelList.add(new ToggleModel("❝ Ramzan ka wo Mahina jis me Quraan ka Nuzool hua saari Insaniyat ki Hidayat aur Rahnumai ke liye.❞\n" +
                        " Surah Baqrah 2:185"));

myrecyclerview.setAdapter(new HadeesAdapter(toggleModelList ,getActivity()));
```

And Remove `data` from adapter

```
public HadeesAdapter(List<ToggleModel> toggleModelList, Context context) {
    this.toggleModelList = toggleModelList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return toggleModelList.size();
}
```

Comment: Great. I also added Hadees.java file. Can you please have a look. It gives me  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0  Error.

Comment: Now try again :)